# react-router-dom doesn't work for my project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I installed react-router-dom to switch between navbar elements. The library does not want to cooperate with my project. After clicking on the navbar element I am not redirected to the required component. Sometimes when I click on a selected item the menu moves slightly to the left. My code looks like this:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Navbar.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import App from '../components/App'
import About from '../components/About';
import Services from '../components/Services';
import Contact from '../components/Contact';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
  } from "react-router-dom";



  

const Navbar = () => {

        const [navLinkOpen, navLinkToggle] = useState(false);

        const handleNavLinksToggle = () => {
            navLinkToggle(!navLinkOpen);
        };

        const renderClasses = () => {
            let classes = "navlinks";
            

            if(navLinkOpen) {
                classes += " ' ' + active";
            }
            return classes;
        };
    return (
        <nav>
            <div className="logo">
                <h4>Delightartco</h4>
            </div>
                <ul className={renderClasses()}>
                    <Router>
                        <li className="link"><Link to={"/home"}>Home</Link></li>
                        <li className="link"><Link to={"/about"}>About</Link></li>
                        <li className="link"><Link to={"/services"}>Services</Link></li>
                        <li className="link"><Link to={"/contact"}>Contact</Link></li> 
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/home" component={App}>
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/about" component={About}>
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/services" component={Services}>
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}>
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                    </Router>     
                </ul>
            <div onClick={handleNavLinksToggle} className="hamburger-toggle">
                <i className="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../src/App.css';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Wrapper from './Wrapper';
import {Content, Winnie, Testimonials, Values, Secrets, Footer} from '../components/Content';



function App() {
      return (
          <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Wrapper />
            <Content />
            <Winnie />
            <Testimonials />
            <Values />
            <Secrets />
            <Footer />
          </div>
      )
}


export default App;
```

Comment: There was also a problem that react freezes browsers (Mozilla Developer Edition, Chrome and Brave). Everything is theoretically correct in the code. I provide a link to the page on Sanbox.  https://r9f56.csb.app/

Comment: @Ajeet Shah  @Hussain Nawaz Lalee Thanks for the clarification. I would also like to ask why the Services.js component renders the content of App.js even though I don't have anything like that in the Services function. For example when I put Navbar.js in the Services.js component this item is displayed as 3rd container. The first are Navbar, Wrapper, and again Navbar.<br/>         
`import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar';


function Services() {
    return (
        <Navbar />
    )
}

export default Services;` [link](https://imgur.com/a/xyBt4Su)

Comment: @Ajeet Shah There is one more problem with the operation of the application. When I switch in Navbar to Services.js. all components located in App.js are displayed there. Why is this happening? There is nothing in Services.js yet. It still renders the content of App.js

Comment: @Ajeet Shah  Yes, this is the latest app link.

Comment: @Ajeet Shah Thank you so much for your help. It works for me. My last question is how to stop displaying the main component, i.e. App.js, e.g. in Services.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are few issues in your code:

1. `App` is your root React component, and you gave it a route: `<Route path="/home" component={App}></Route>`. This is causing a recursive / infinite loop. `App` component inside `App` component.
2. Code structure looks complex.

Here is a proposed fixed code:

**index.jsx:**

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**App.jsx:**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <StrictMode>
      <Routes />
    </StrictMode>
  );
}
```

**Routes.jsx:**

```
export default function Routes() {
  return (
    <Router>

      {/* Route components would be visible only at their route */}
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/services" component={Services}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}></Route>
      </Switch>

      {/* Below components would be visible always at UI */}
      <Navbar />     {/* Top navigation Link's */}
      <Wrapper />
      <Content />
      <Winnie />
      <Testimonials />
      <Values />
      <Secrets />
      <Footer />     {/* Bottom navigation Link's */}
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does that mean the content of `Services.js` is completely different from what I saw (your main landing page) when trying?

Comment: Currently the content of Services.js is empty. There is an empty div. When I click on the Services.js item in Navbar I see the content of App.js in it. For example if I only put Navbar element and render it in Services.js it appears twice, one after the other. What does this situation result from?

Comment: Create a new component - **Landing.jsx** and put `<Wrapper />`, `<Content />`, `<Winnie />`, `<Testimonials />`, `<Values />`, `<Secrets />` in it. Add a route: `<Route exact path="/" component={Landing}></Route>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to keep in mind when using `react-router`.

1. The `Router` or `BrowserRouter` component should wrap all your routes and your links. Generally, if your app does not need more than one `Router`, its better to wrap your whole App with the Router.
2. The `Link` component's job is to simply navigate to the page and can be used anywhere you want to show a link to someplace e.g. in the `Navbar`.
3. The `Route` (not Router) component's placement is very important. It should be placed where you want to render the content. In your code you are rendering the routes in the `Navbar` and are unable to see the routes being rendered due to invalid / improper structure.

**Navbar.js**

Your Navbar should only contain the links while the `Router` should be on the top-level and the `Switch / Routes` should be placed where you want to render the content.

```
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav>
      {/* Move `Router` to top-level e.g. in App.js */}
      <ul>
        <li className="link">
          <Link to={"/home"}>Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="link">
          <Link to={"/about"}>About</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="link">
          <Link to={"/services"}>Services</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="link">
          <Link to={"/contact"}>Contact</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      {/* Move `Switch and Routes` to where you want to render the content e.g. in Content.js */}
    </nav>
  );
}
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <Wrapper />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={App}></Route>
          <Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
          <Route path="/services" component={Services}></Route>
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}></Route>
        </Switch>
        <Winnie />
        <Testimonials />
        <Values />
        <Secrets />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```